# Passport JS passport.use doesn't work in exports.function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Hello LocalStrategy from passportJS doesn't work :

```
    exports.checkIt = function(req, res, next){
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done){
            console.log(username);
            models.User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(!user){
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown User' });
                }
                var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
                bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, password, function(err, isMatch){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    if(isMatch){
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid Password' });
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
        models.User.findById(id, function(err, user){
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/obs', failureRedirect: '/connection', failureFlash: true });
};
```

CheckIt is called from route : app.post('/connection', auth.checkIt);

The "console.log(username)" does not appear in the console.

Comment: Try setting up passport (.use, .serializeUser, .deserializeUser) in whatever module configures express instead of inside the route.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've created "services" folder and add "passport.js" file. I import this file in "server.js" file and I add "passport.authenticate" to "app.post('/login', passport.authenticate ...) in routes... Don't know if it's the best way.